# Webpack 5: sass doesn't find path for images

Tags: image, webpack, path

I'm just starting with webpack.
I have problem while trying to reach  my images in my scss files.
The only way I seem to succeed is by using the following path format:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.158), rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.151)), url('/Users/username/Desktop/Web_Design/MyDesk/webpack-project/src/images/bg.jpg');
```

anything else from that such as this:

```
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.158), rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.151)), url('../../images/bg.jpg');
```

will cause the following compilation error:

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/main.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '../../images/bg.jpg' in '/Users/username/Desktop/Web_Design/MyDesk/webpack-project/src/scss'
```

This is my webpack configuration:

```
const path = require("path");
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

let mode = 'development'
let target = 'web'

const plugins = [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
   
  ];

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    mode= 'production',
    target = 'browserslist'
}

module.exports = {
    mode: mode,
    target: target,
    output:{
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      assetModuleFilename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]',
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(s[ac]|c)ss$/i,
            use: [
              {
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                // This is required for asset imports in CSS, such as url()
                // options: { publicPath: "" },
                options: { publicPath: "./src/" },
              },
              "css-loader",
              "postcss-loader",
              // according to the docs, sass-loader should be at the bottom, which
              // loads it first to avoid prefixes in your sourcemaps and other issues.
              "sass-loader",
            ],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
            /**
             * The `type` setting replaces the need for "url-loader"
             * and "file-loader" in Webpack 5.
             *
             * setting `type` to "asset" will automatically pick between
             * outputing images to a file, or inlining them in the bundle as base64
             * with a default max inline size of 8kb
             */
            type: "asset",
            parser:{
              dataUrlCondition:{
                maxSize: 30 * 1024,
              }

            },
    
            /**
             * If you want to inline larger images, you can set
             * a custom `maxSize` for inline like so:
             */
            // parser: {
            //   dataUrlCondition: {
            //     maxSize: 30 * 1024,
            //   },
            // },
          },
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              // without additional settings, this will reference .babelrc
              loader: "babel-loader",
              options: {
                /**
                 * From the docs: When set, the given directory will be used
                 * to cache the results of the loader. Future webpack builds
                 * will attempt to read from the cache to avoid needing to run
                 * the potentially expensive Babel recompilation process on each run.
                 */
                cacheDirectory: true,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    
      plugins: plugins,
    
      target: target,
    
      devtool: "source-map",
    
      resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
      },
    
      // required if using webpack-dev-server
      devServer: {
        contentBase: "./dist",
        hot: true,
      },
    };
```

Any idea what might help me to solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you want to use `parser` then remove this line `assetModuleFilename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]'` but you may need `publicPath`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Long shot here, but it looks like you have the same file structure as my project, so you might only need to go up one directory for your import (i.e. `../images/bg.jpg` rather than `../../images/bg.jpg`).

I get the same error as you when I look two directories up, though it may be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my problem was with my publicPath configuration. I had to modify it to:

```
{
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                // This is required for asset imports in CSS, such as url()
                options: { publicPath: "." },
              },
```

Once I did this to my puclicPath I could just load my url ims like this:

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.158), rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.151)),url('../images/bg.jpg');
```